# Compare 2 seperate csv files and write difference to a new csv file - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, compare

I am trying to compare two csv files in python and save the difference to a third csv file in python 2.7.

```
import csv

f1 = open ("olddata/file1.csv")
oldFile1 = csv.reader(f1)
oldList1 = []
for row in oldFile1:
    oldList1.append(row)

f2 = open ("newdata/file2.csv")
oldFile2 = csv.reader(f2)
oldList2 = []
for row in oldFile2:
    oldList2.append(row)

f1.close()
f2.close()

set1 = tuple(oldList1)
set2 = tuple(oldList2)

print oldList2.difference(oldList1)
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare.py", line 21, in <module>
    print oldList2.difference(oldList1)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'difference'
```

I am new to python, and coding in general, and I am not done with this code just yet (I have to make sure to store the differences to a variable and write the difference to a new csv file.). I have been trying to solve this all day and I simply can't. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are confusing `list` with `set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by difference? The answer to that gives you two distinct possibilities.

If a row is considered same when **all columns** are same, then you can get your answer via the following code:

```
import csv

f1 = open ("olddata/file1.csv")
oldFile1 = csv.reader(f1)
oldList1 = []
for row in oldFile1:
    oldList1.append(row)

f2 = open ("newdata/file2.csv")
oldFile2 = csv.reader(f2)
oldList2 = []
for row in oldFile2:
    oldList2.append(row)

f1.close()
f2.close()

print [row for row in oldList1 if row not in oldList2]
```

However, if two rows are same if a **certain key field (i.e. column)** is same, then the following code will give you your answer:

```
import csv

f1 = open ("olddata/file1.csv")
oldFile1 = csv.reader(f1)
oldList1 = []
for row in oldFile1:
    oldList1.append(row)

f2 = open ("newdata/file2.csv")
oldFile2 = csv.reader(f2)
oldList2 = []
for row in oldFile2:
    oldList2.append(row)

f1.close()
f2.close()

keyfield = 0 # Change this for choosing the column number

oldList2keys = [row[keyfield] for row in oldList2]
print [row for row in oldList1 if row[keyfield] not in oldList2keys]
```

**Note:** The above code might run slow for extremely large files. If instead, you wish to speed up code through hashing, you can use `set` after converting the `oldList`s using the following code:

```
set1 = set(tuple(row) for row in oldList1)
set2 = set(tuple(row) for row in oldList2)
```

After this, you can use `set1.difference(set2)`

Comment: Sorry, i should have been clearer about that. I meant to say when all columns are the same so i used the edit you made and it worked. The problem is that now i want to write the output to a csv file.

Comment: Also @Jay Bosamiya, thanks for the answer. forgot about that part.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct: tuple has no "difference" method.

I guess you want to use set (and make the elements immutable)?

```
set1 = set([tuple(item) for item in oldList1])
set2 = set([tuple(item) for item in oldList2])
```

Comment: when I change it to a set it gives me the error unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Indeed, you can convert the items of your lists (which were also lists) to tuples. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def read_csv_file(filename):
    res = []
    with open(filename) as f:
         for line in csv.reader(f):
               res.append(line)


oldList1 = read_csv_file("olddata/file1.csv")
oldList2 = read_csv_file("olddata/file2.csv")


difference_list = []

for a,b in zip(oldList1,oldList2):
   if a != b:
       difference_list.append(a + '\t' + b)
```

Eventually you have a list of items and you can just write them to file.

EDIT:
In this situation, [a,b,c] vs [b,c,a] will fail.  If you know that [a,b,c] vs [b,c,a] should return no difference, use the following code pls.

```
import csv

def read_csv_file(filename):
    res = []
    with open(filename) as f:
         for line in csv.reader(f):
               res.append(line)


oldList1 = read_csv_file("olddata/file1.csv")
oldList2 = read_csv_file("olddata/file2.csv")


difference_list = []

for a in oldList1:
  for b in oldList2:
    if a != b:
       difference_list.append(a + '\t' + b)
```

Comment: Please, be a nice person, change copy-paste on a function ;)
p.s. Your code will fail on [a,b,c] vs [b,c,a]

Comment: @Jimilian you are right! let me think about how to fix it, if you know how to fix it, would love to get your input :-)

Comment: @Jimilian thanks so much for cleaning up my code, I will add in another option if the author of the question knows that [a,b,c] vs [b,c,a] shouldn't fail

Comment: Now I get the following error message 'can only concatenate list (not str ) to list'... I'm starting to think i have to start from scratch again.

Comment: @Kevin Zhao, if you are trying to do it without set and without square complexity, you should iterate through one list and remove elements from other list. Switch them and repeat. After this two operations you will receive two list with unique elements.

Comment: What if both lists contain same elements but in different order?