# CSV compare column values python

Tags: python, csv

I've 2 csv files as **csv1** and **csv2** respectively.

**csv1**

```
1,9,10
2,10,11
3,11,10
```

**csv2**

```
2,b
1,a
3,c
```

I want to check each value of 1st column of **csv1** to 1st column of **csv2** and if there is a match the other value of 2nd column of **csv2** is appended to **csv1**. 
My final output would be :

```
1,9,10,a
2,10,11,b
3,11,10,c
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852710/compare-2-seperate-csv-files-and-write-difference-to-a-new-csv-file-python-2-7/30853120#30853120

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSV module of python to read the files. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Compare the two files using for loop and write result into a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

**Algo**:

1. Use **`csv` module** to read and writer csv file.
2. Create Dictionary structure of csv file 2
3. Open new file in write mode.
4. Open csv file 1 in read mode.
5. Iterate every row in csv file 1.
6. check first item from the row is present in dictionary (Point 2).
7. If 6 is true then append value from the dictionary to current row.
8. Write row into file.(Point 3).

**code**:

```
import csv
# Create Dictionary structure of csv file 2
with open("/home/vivek/2.csv", "rb") as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp,)
    root2 = {}
    for i in root:
        root2[i[0]] = i[1]

print "Debug 1: Dictionary of file 2:", root2

with open("/home/vivek/output.csv", "wb") as fp:
    with open("/home/vivek/1.csv", "rb") as fp1:
        output = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=",")
        root = csv.reader(fp1,)
        for i in root:
            #Check first item from the row is present in dictionary.  
            if i[0] in root2:
                i.append(root2[i[0]])
            output.writerow(i)
```

---

List **Append Vs Concatenation:**

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def addtest():
...   l = []
...   for i in range(1000): 
...       l +[i]
... 
>>> def appendtest():
...   l = []
...   for i in range(1000): 
...       l.append(i)
... 
>>> print "Time 1:", timeit.timeit('appendtest()', 'from __main__ import appendtest')
Time 1: 110.55152607
>>> print "Time 1:", timeit.timeit('addtest()', 'from __main__ import addtest')
Time 1: 265.882155895
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you need, it makes use of Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. It first reads the whole of `csv2` into a dictionary which can then be used to see if the key is present whilst reading `csv1`:

```
import csv  

d_csv2 = {}

with open('2.csv', 'r') as f_csv2:
    csv_2 = csv.reader(f_csv2)
    for cols in csv_2:
        d_csv2[cols[0]] = cols[1]

with open('1.csv', 'r') as f_csv1, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_1 = csv.reader(f_csv1)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for cols in csv_1:
        if cols[0] in d_csv2:
            csv_output.writerow(cols + [d_csv2[cols[0]]])
```

It creates the following `output.csv` file:

```
1,9,10,a
2,10,11,b
3,11,10,c
```

Comment: Yup, we can write `with` statements in one line,  `concatenation` of list will take more time then `append`