# Python: How to write the difference of two CSV files, with one having a subset of columns, in a new CSV file

Tags: python, csv, set, dataset

Parent CSV file:

```
Name   ID    Address   Age   Phone   Email
John   123   New York  32    24...   email@something.some
George 231   London    24    21...   email2@something.some
Adam   321   Berlin    12    71...   email3@something.some
...  ....   ...       ...   ...     ...
```

Second CSV file:

```
Name   ID    Age       Email
Adam   321   Berlin    email3@something.some
George 231   London    email2@something.some
...  ....   ...        ...
```

I've been trying to create a new CSV file that contains data from the first CSV file but NOT in the second CSV file with an additional column info(ie. wanting to include the address data as well for the respective ID) so that new CSV file would look like:

```
Name   ID    Age       Address    Email
John   123   New York  32    24...   email@something.some
...  ....   ...        ...            ...
```

I've tried using this method 
[Compare 2 seperate csv files and write difference to a new csv file - Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852710/compare-2-seperate-csv-files-and-write-difference-to-a-new-csv-file-python-2-7)
 but I can't include the 'address' column (known index) to write it in the new CSV file while also pulling and writing the difference of the rest. Maybe there's a faster option that would run by the ID and write it immediately to the new file.

Comment: Your example file has 5 headers and 6 values, please correct it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you want these columns:

```
Name   ID    Age       Address    Email
```

You can do that using dictionaries, You make a dictionary for the first file, key being the ID and value being the row. Then you can see what Ids you need and rebuild each row as you want.

```
import csv

# Make a dictionary from the first file (id, row)
f1 = open ("file1.csv")
file1 = csv.reader(f1)
file1RowDict = {}
for row in file1:
    file1RowDict[row[1]] = row
f1.close()

# Make a list of all the Ids in the second file
f2 = open ("file2.csv")
file2 = csv.reader(f2)
file2Ids = []
for row in file2:
    file2Ids.append(row[1])
f2.close()


# Find Ids which are only on the first file
ids = [id for id in file1RowDict.keys() if id not in file2Ids]

newFileRows = []
# Grab the header row and reorder as you want
headerRow = file1RowDict['ID']
headerRow = [headerRow[0], headerRow[1], headerRow[3], headerRow[2], headerRow[5]]
newFileRows.append(headerRow)
# Grab each data row and reorder as you want
for id in ids: 
    row = file1RowDict[id]
    newRow = [row[0], row[1], row[3], row[2], row[5]]
    newFileRows.append(newRow)

print(str(newFileRows))
```

Outputs:

```
[
  ['Name', 'ID', 'Age', 'Address', 'Email'], 
  ['John', '123', '32', 'New York', 'email@something.some']
]
```